# Inserting X rows of data into spreadsheet between two rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly novice at VBA but I'm looking to use a userform to do the following:
1) find an order which will be scanned in (I know how to do this part)
2) insert multiple new orders between the order that is scanned in and the next order (may be only 1 new order, may be up to 20), while preserving the formulas I have in place.
I'm just looking for some ideas on how to make the userform populate additional boxes for new orders and then have the program move the other orders down and put the new ones in place.

as I've said, I know how to get it to find the last order (which will be where the new orders will be cut in) but not sure how to best use the userform functionality to make a list of the new orders and then using VBA to move the other orders down to make room for the new ones

I don't currently have any code for this yet, just looking for ideas.

Just want to be able to put a new series of order numbers between 2 existing orders.

Comment: Record a macro of you doing it manually, and then look at the code it gives you. That would give you a good start.

Comment: That's actually how I started learning to code in VBA in the first place, recording then seeing what the code was for it. The problem here is I need a much more adaptive set of coding. It was a good idea though.

Comment: Just record a Macro for a scenario. If you can not see how to modify your code, then post it and place some comments regarding your variables (which section of your code should be variable).

Comment: Ok, here is an idea for you: add the orders to the bottom of a table, sort the table, then call it a day and go out drinking with your buddies.  You could be done with your project and honing your skill at darts instead of trying to figure out how to start the thing.  If you don't know what to do or how to do it, shouldn't you ask if the added complexity is really worth the cost?  Beer doesn't drink itself, it needs you there to make it happen!